# submit button not working inside Curl content PHP

Tags: php, curl, post

I am using the following code to display another website's onmy site with Curl PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init($turl);

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($form_data));
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  $data = curl_exec( $ch );
echo $data
```

I replace all the links inside the content before displaying it and everything works OK. In addition, I also replaced:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
```

with

```
 <form action="http://siteurl.com/login.php" method="post">
```

But although all submit buttons and post forms inside the content are not working. Why is this?

In addition, can I allow external sites to use user cookies when I call them with Curl PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `=` in your code

```
<form action="http://siteurl.com/login.php" method"post">
```

needs to be

```
<form action="http://siteurl.com/login.php" method="post">
```

Comment: yes i know it was just a mistake this is not the problem

Comment: if that is the case, please edit your post so it is exactly like the code you are using.